# How to flatten a list of lists when the root type is List[Any]

Tags: scala

I have code that computes the cross product of multiple lists and generates a list of lists but the root type is `List[Any]` so if I try to do:

```
val result : List[Any] = computedListOfLists() 
// result is List(List(List(0.1, 1), a), List(List(0.1, 1), b), List(List(0.1, 2), a), List(List(0.1, 2), b), List(List(0.1, 3), a), List(List(0.1, 3), b), List(List(0.01, 1), a), List(List(0.01, 1), b), List(List(0.01, 2), a), List(List(0.01, 2), b), List(List(0.01, 3), a), List(List(0.01, 3), b), List(List(0.001, 1), a), List(List(0.001, 1), b), List(List(0.001, 2), a), List(List(0.001, 2), b), List(List(0.001, 3), a), List(List(0.001, 3), b))

result.flatten // will not compile
```

Comment: Then the problem is probably somewhere higher up in the code, since the type of the `List` you're getting isn't accurate enough.

Comment: How did you get an `Any` in the first place? Sounds fishy to me.

Comment: What output do you expect? flatten is not recursive.

Comment: I know it sounds fishy but this code is part of a framework that extends Scalatest. It is impossible to build Table manually so we generate cross product or permutation of the input arrays and therefore the need for this use case ... the inputs to Table are variable arguments so no idea what the fixed types or sizes of the tuples are.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot directly use `flatten` however you can define a function like this:

```
def flatten(l: List[Any]): List[Any] = l flatMap {
  case list: List[_] => flatten(list)
  case e => List(e)
}
```

And call like this:

```
val l = List(
  List(List(0.1, 1), "a"),
  List(List(0.1, 1), "b"),
  List(List(0.1, 2), "a"),
  List(List(0.1, 2), "b"),
  List(List(0.1, 3), "a"),
  List(List(0.1, 3), "b"),
  List(List(0.01, 1), "a"),
  List(List(0.01, 1), "b"),
  List(List(0.01, 2), "a"),
  List(List(0.01, 2), "b"),
  List(List(0.01, 3), "a"),
  List(List(0.01, 3), "b"),
  List(List(0.001, 1), "a"),
  List(List(0.001, 1), "b"),
  List(List(0.001, 2), "a"),
  List(List(0.001, 2), "b"),
  List(List(0.001, 3), "a"),
  List(List(0.001, 3), "b"))

flatten(l)
```

The result would be:

```
List[Any] = List(0.1, 1.0, a, 0.1, 1.0, b, 0.1, 2.0, a, 0.1, 2.0, b, 0.1, 3.0, a, 0.1, 3.0, b, 0.01, 1.0, a, 0.01, 1.0, b, 0.01, 2.0, a, 0.01, 2.0, b, 0.01, 3.0, a, 0.01, 3.0, b, 0.001, 1.0, a, 0.001, 1.0, b, 0.001, 2.0, a, 0.001, 2.0, b, 0.001, 3.0, a, 0.001, 3.0, b)
```

Comment: It's not clear if OP wants to recurse into `List(List(List(1,2,3)))` but flatten does not.